# Merging two variables in one and equaling it with another one

Tags: javascript, html

The code doesn’t have any error, but doesn’t work. I fill both inputs and click the button but it doesn’t print out the words.

```js
let listItem = document.getElementById('todoListItem');
let timeInputValue = document.getElementById('timeInput');
let getInputValue = document.getElementById('task');
let errorMessageInput = document.getElementById('errorMsg');

function addTask() {
  if (getInputValue.value.trim() === "") {
    errorMessageInput.textContent = "You haven't added a todo item, please add it in order to show up";
    
    return;
  }

  let myTodoInput = listItem.textContent;
  let myTodoTime = timeInputValue.textContent;
  let myTodoInfo = myTodoInput + ' Time ' + myTodoTime;

  myTodoInfo = getInputValue.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="myApp border border-info">
  <p class="text-center appTittle">To Do List</p>
  <div class="todoThings" id="todo">
    <ul>
      <li id="todoListItem"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <p class="mr-3 ml-3 appTaskText">Task</p><input type="text" class="appInput" id="task">
    <p class="mr-1 ml-3 appTaskText">Time</p><input type="number" id="timeInput" min="1" max="24">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm addButton" id="add" onclick="addTask()">Add task</button>
  <p id="errorMsg" class="text-danger mt-1 mb-1"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. ID selectors are meaningless without the corresponding HTML.

Comment: Where are you trying to print out something into the DOM, other than in the error handler? Why are you setting `myTodoInfo`, then immediately setting it to something completely different? You’re also not using `myTodoInfo` at all.

Comment: What if you try moving the getElementById pieces into the function? It's might be referencing them before they exist on the page

Comment: @defenestr8me _“The code doesn’t have any error”_, apparently.

Comment: You are just doing it the wrong way, reverse both sides of your expressions.

Comment: I guess i know what you are trying to do. You want to add a name to a task and a time. And then show it in a list. Then add more tasks to that list. But you are doing it very wrong. From the variable names which have nothing to do with their actual values to the logic. Please review your code, make a little bit of research and change the description of the question so it's more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
let myTodoInput = listItem.textContent;
let myTodoTime = timeInputValue.textContent;
let myTodoInfo = myTodoInput + ' Time ' + myTodoTime; // line isn't of value as it is overwritten below
myTodoInfo = getInputValue.value; // overwrites declaration.`
```

You are not printing anyway. No `console.log()` or `alert()` and no DOM injection.

Comment: They aren't trying to `console.log` or `alert`. They are referencing the variable in the HTML file.

Comment: He says in initial write up `print out the words`

Comment: Yes to the page not the console

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, I might have not explained it properly and I barely know hence I'm new. By printing what I actually meant was make it show on listItem and not print in console or alert.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the full solution, However, i have corrected the variables to fix the basic issue of not showing the task. You should get some help with this solution and extend it.

```js
let listItem = document.getElementById('todoListItem');
let timeInputValue = document.getElementById('timeInput');
let getInputValue = document.getElementById('task');
let errorMessageInput = document.getElementById('errorMsg');

function addTask() {
  if (getInputValue.value.trim() === "") {
    errorMessageInput.textContent = "You haven't added a todo item, please add it in order to show up";

    return;
  }

  let myTodoInput = getInputValue.value;
  let myTodoTime = timeInputValue.value;
  let myTodoInfo = myTodoInput + ' Time ' + myTodoTime;

  myTodoInfo = getInputValue.value;
  listItem.innerHTML = myTodoInfo;
}
```

```html
<div class="myApp border border-info">
  <p class="text-center appTittle">To Do List</p>
  <div class="todoThings" id="todo">
    <ul>
      <li id="todoListItem"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <p class="mr-3 ml-3 appTaskText">Task</p><input type="text" class="appInput" id="task">
    <p class="mr-1 ml-3 appTaskText">Time</p><input type="number" id="timeInput" min="1" max="24">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm addButton" id="add" onclick="addTask()">Add task</button>
  <p id="errorMsg" class="text-danger mt-1 mb-1"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue this is the fix

```
let listItem = document.getElementById('todoListItem');
let timeInputValue = document.getElementById('timeInput');
let getInputValue = document.getElementById('task');
let errorMessageInput = document.getElementById('errorMsg');

function addTask() {
    if (getInputValue.value.trim() === "") {
        errorMessageInput.textContent = "You haven't added a todo item, please add it in order to show up";
        return;
    }

    let myTodoInput = getInputValue.value;
    let myTodoTime = timeInputValue.value;
    let myTodoInfo = myTodoInput + ' at ' + myTodoTime + 'PM';

    listItem.textContent = myTodoInfo;
}
```

Comment: No,with this you'll have only one list item in the end